# Change the default color of input component typing area line's color

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ionic3

Do you know how to change the default color of [**input component**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/) typing area line's color? I was unable to find out either any `SasS variable` or a custom way to do that.

Here is [**the Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iKS6Jd?p=preview)

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password Input"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you override the default theme ? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/7c0fe93061fc17d1e023698983b7b58d9b82f0a9/src/components/input/input.wp.scss

Comment: The problem here is there is no predefined variable for above use case. @Vega

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ionic input sass file (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/input/input.scss)

You should just be able to edit the `$text-input-placeholder-color` variable

Comment: Nope. It changes the color of the `placeholder text`. I need to change the typing area's default color as shown on my image above.

Comment: `.list-md .item-input {
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }`

That's the selector for the border for the input, although there may be a more graceful way of applying this

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `home.page.scss`:

```
ion-item {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 red;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Important is that not the input has a border but the wrapping ion-item.
If You also want to change the border when the input is focused:

```
ion-item.input-has-focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 green;
}
```

Comment: This is not working. This will draw another new line on top of the input's line.  Any clue to avoid that?

Comment: Not working.Here you can see the out put. https://i.imgur.com/s9wc3TY.png

Comment: It draws an extra line.

Comment: Oh I just tried with your Plunker, I don't know whats going on in your real application.

Comment: You know that, according to the validation rules that color should change.But that part is not working with your style. On such use case, it shows both lines.

Comment: OK I see, that part seems to be missing in the plunker. I updated the plunker again with an example on how to access the _invalid_ state and how to remove the box-shadow and border on item-inner, you can play around with that to achieve what you exactly want to do. Maybe some advice to cover all of the states: use chrome dev-tools an inspect the ion-item an check which classes get added/removed when you change something and then override them in you scss to change the behaviour your way.

Comment: It seems this is a very complicated scenario. I have decided to ask a SaaS variable from the Ionic team.Then we just need to change that color only. They have given it for a placeholder like this `$text-input-placeholder-color`. When I applied your latest style to my app it looks like this :( https://i.imgur.com/RUvQP49.png

Comment: That will probably take longer than implementing it yourself as they are currently busy finishing version 4 of the framework. Well as I said you will have to play around with different settings of the styles to achieve exactly what you want - good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just added following scss for change default area color and border-color

```
.list-md .item-input {
      background:#ccc;
      border-bottom-color:black;

      &.item-input-has-focus:last-child,
      &.input-has-focus:last-child {
        background:#fff;
        border-bottom-color:red;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 red;
      }
 }
```

Working [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/B2RApYyqF70ssh9Bfa2Y?p=preview)

Comment: Not working.It affects only the last line.See the image: https://i.imgur.com/qyp3tuU.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
ion-item:not(.error) .item-inner {
  border-color: deeppink !important; // Lines will be pink
}
```

in your **app.scss** file or any other file where you put "global" style for your app.

**EDIT:** The "*:not(.error)*" part added here should prevent the pink line to be displayed when there is a validation error on the input.

Comment: This is not working as expected. You know that if we typed the correct text then it should change to green color.But your line also there with the green line.Please see the image here. https://i.imgur.com/laLX8TX.png

Comment: It seems that your Plunker is different than your real application, so the style used in your app is not exactly the same than in your Plunker.
Can you try to fill your Plunker with the same HTML structure than in your app ? (I mean by adding the same _ion-list_, _ion-item_, _ion-input_ etc. and the same attributes you used)

Comment: You know that, according to the validation rules that color should change.But that part is not working with your style. On such use case, it shows both lines. That is the only difference with my app and above plunker.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the Sass variables **$text-input-highlight-color-invalid** and **$text-input-highlight-color-valid** ? (Indications here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/ )

Comment: I don't need to override those.those are working fine. On such use cases, I need to remove the default line.But it is not happening when I used your style.  https://i.imgur.com/laLX8TX.png

Comment: Can you copy&paste me the HTML code of the input element when the validation fail (and there is a red line below your input element) ? So I can see the classes and attributes of the input at this precise moment.